# The file is not an updated package - Sitecore

Tags: sitecore

When I installed package in Sitecore I am getting error "the file is not an updated package". The package "C:\InetPub\wwwroot..\Website\sitecore\admin\packages\File1..TDSMaster.Files.update" could not be loaded. The file is not an updated package. Can any one help?

Comment: How are you trying to install this package? Using the Sitecore `Installation Wizard` via the desktop meno or from `/sitecore/admin/UpdateInstallationWizard.aspx`. Update packages need to be done via this page, zip files through the desktop wizard.

Comment: I have installed through ../sitecore/admin/UpdateInstallationWizard.aspx

Comment: I'm getting the error, but for different reasons. Btw, I don't think you can even use a .update package file from the Installation wizard.

Comment: During my test, for what is worth, I noticed the attributes of the zip file inside the update file had Archive, while the invalid one didn't.

Comment: @BalaSM: How did you create this package?

Comment: To me, the package was a sort of experiment hand made. Using 7zip library from powershell as opposed to standard zip libraries did the trick.